# Rolling a custom function over pandas series in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, finance

I have a pandas series

```
Date
2016-11-01    100000.000000
2016-11-02    100500.648302
2016-11-03    100481.450478
2016-11-04     99550.193742
2016-11-07    101913.648567
```

I am trying to calculate a rolling sharpe ratio on this series. The formula for the sharpe ratio is

```
sharpe = np.sqrt(252)*(average_daily_returns/volatility)
```

where we can calculate daily returns as

```
daily_returns = (series/series.shift(1))-1
daily_returns = daily_returns[1:]
```

then average _daily_returns becomes

```
average_daily_returns = daily_returns.mean()
```

and volatility becomes

```
volatility = daily_returns.std()
```

I am trying to roll the sharpe ratio over the series. So I want to calculate the sharpe ratio for day 1 then day 1 and day 2 then day 1 and day 2 and day 3 then day 1 and day 2 and ... and day n where n is the last date in the series.

I have created the following function:

```
def sharpe(s): 
    daily_returns = (s/s.shift(1))-1
    daily_returns = daily_returns[1:]
    average_daily_returns = daily_returns.mean()
    volatility = daily_returns.std()
    sharpe = np.sqrt(252)*(average_daily_returns/volatility)
```

This above function will calculate the sharpe ratio for each series passed in. I want to roll this function over the series. So, roll this function on (2016-11-01) then on (2016-11-01 and 2016-11-02) then on (2016-11-01 and 2016-11-02 and 2016-01-03) ...

I have looked at pandas.rolling_apply and the doccumentation (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_apply.html) but I can not get this to work with my function. It seems that the rolling_apply is only working when I do a function such as a sum, mean, or simple calculation like that. I have tried many variations of this but nothing has worked so far. For instance using

```
(pv.rolling(2)).apply(#I am not sure how I can fit the sharpe ratio function in here)
```

Comment: What would be desired output? A new series with this rolled function? Please post what data would look given example series of 5 items.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a list comprehension using the `Date` index to build a pandas Series. Each element is a filtered series by dates passed into the `sharpe()` function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series([100000.000000, 100500.648302, 100481.450478, 99550.193742, 101913.648567],
                 index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2016-11-01', '2016-11-02', '2016-11-03',
                                         '2016-11-04', '2016-11-07'], name='Date'))
print(data)
# Date
# 2016-11-01    100000.000000
# 2016-11-02    100500.648302
# 2016-11-03    100481.450478
# 2016-11-04     99550.193742
# 2016-11-07    101913.648567
# dtype: float64

def sharpe(s): 
    daily_returns = (s/s.shift(1))-1
    daily_returns = daily_returns[1:]
    average_daily_returns = daily_returns.mean()
    volatility = daily_returns.std()
    sharpe = np.sqrt(252)*(average_daily_returns/volatility)
    return(sharpe)

newdata = pd.Series([sharpe(data[data.index <= d]) for d in data.index.values],
                   index=pd.DatetimeIndex(data.index.values, name='Date'))    
print(newdata)
# Date
# 2016-11-01          NaN
# 2016-11-02          NaN
# 2016-11-03    10.399878
# 2016-11-04    -3.261154
# 2016-11-07     5.497725
# dtype: float64
```

Comment: How come the first two rows are NaN in the dataframe newdata? Shouldn't the first one just be NaN?

Comment: Print statement shows volatility returns `nan` on the first and second dates. [Pandas series std](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.std.html) uses sample standard deviation with degrees of freedom N-1. Even with `ddof=0` which equates to `np.std(daily_returns)` returns *inf* which is the divide by zero error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this quite late.  Perhaps expanding() is new to Pandas since your question.

You can use the pandas [expanding()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html), and use apply there.  I have copied your calculation of the Sharpe ratio (and simplified it using pct_change() for the daily return) and used it within the lambda apply, and it returns a series of the ratios over time.

```
series = pd.Series(data=[100000.000000, 100500.648302, 100481.450478, 99550.193742, 101913.648567], index=["2016-11-01", "2016-11-02", "2016-11-03", "2016-11-04", "2016-11-07"])

sharpe_ratios = series.expanding().apply(lambda x: 252**0.5 * (x.pct_change().mean() / x.pct_change().std()))

print(sharpe_ratios)
#Output: 
#2016-11-01          NaN
#2016-11-02          NaN
#2016-11-03    10.399878
#2016-11-04    -3.261154
#2016-11-07     5.497725
#dtype: float64
```